Recreating the results shown in the following Figure: Textbook: DIGITAL SIGNAL PROCESSING IN MODERN COMMUNICATION SYSTEMS 2ed

I wrote the following code in MATLAB (the compared sequences are B[n] and C[n] provided in the code):
% Define the sequences B[n] and C[n]
B = [1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 -1];
C = [1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1 1 1];

% Compute the autocorrelation of B and C
[R_B,lags_B] = xcorr(B,B); % Autocorrelation of B
[R_C,lags_C] = xcorr(C,C); % Autocorrelation of C

% Plot autocorrelation of B[n]
figure;clf;
subplot(2,1,1);
stem(lags_B, R_B, 'filled');
title('Autocorrelation of B[n]');
xlabel('Lag');
ylabel('Autocorrelation');
grid on;

% Plot autocorrelation of C[n]
subplot(2,1,2);
stem(lags_C, R_C, 'filled');
title('Autocorrelation of C[n]');
xlabel('Lag');
ylabel('Autocorrelation');
grid on;

And getting the following results instead:


You have to provide the data from the actual question in the book… If we don’t get what the book says, we can’t possibly provide the “correct” answer, or pinpoint what may be wrong.

The graph in the book for  $R_{CC}[n]$ can't be correct since the autocorrelation has even symmetry and the graph doesn't.  Something is clearly missing here.

@ZaellixA It is provided as a demonstration rather than an example or exercise. Sorry for that, anyways I added the screenshot from the book.

@Hilmar My thoughts exactly, just wanted to clarify. Thank you.

The thing that kills me is whatever the heck is that $\frac1N$ factor doing in there when the limits of the summation are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?  Where does $N$ come from?

Okay, I read down a little more.  "The limits on these equations should be taken with a pinch of salt..." - - - - - - Then why is this in a textbook?  I write dumbfuck answers to this SE with more explicit math than that.  A textbook or a published paper really should make sure that all of the "i's" are crossed and the "t's" are dotted.

I don't mind that the limits in the definition are infinite.  But then make sure that the sequences that go into the summation are also defined with infinite limits, even that means explicitly appending zeros on both ends of a finite sequence.

@robertbristow-johnson I see your point now, thank you. I was confused about the fact you are pointing to.

@robertbristow-johnson: The $1/N$ factor is simply wrong. If you look at the figures you'll see that they themselves don't actually use it when computing the autocorrelation. Judging from that page, it doesn't look like the greatest book ...

I think I agree @MattL. Hay there is someone posting about Heisenburg Uncertainty Principle and STFT.  Are you gonna respond to that?  I guess I could, but I think you would be better.

This is clearly an error in the book. What is shown in the plot is the cross-correlation of $B[n]$ and $C[n]$. Note that the definition of cross-correlation in the book is non-standard, and it is different from the one used in Matlab's xcorr. That's why in order to obtain the same plot, we need to use xcorr(C,B) instead of xcorr(B,C), which is just a time/lag reversal, as shown in the following Matlab/Octave code:
B = [1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1];
C = [1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1];
D = xcorr(C,B);
n = -10:10;
stem(n,D)


Got it Thanks @Matt L.

I do wish that text books and papers always had an accompanying website or meta data that provided (so far as practically possible) raw data and code resulting in the embedded plots.

This book has a companion website, but unfortunately, this specific demonstration is not provided.

If the books source code was available as a "Latex-Jupyter-Wolfram"-hybrid, the math and figures should be accessible in a standardised format unless the author explicitly chose to include flat image files. I have scratched my head over enough typos in books to wish for something like that.

Something is likely wrong here. Your MATLAB code produces the expected response output at zero lag with those inputs. The output of the "raw" autocorrelation function at lag zero is:
$$R_{CC}[0] = \sum{C[m]C[m]} = 11$$
The figure for the autocorrelation of $C[n]$ seems to peak at 5, and since the output also doesn't have even symmetry, it's not due to a scaling factor.

Can you please explain what you mean by "scaling factor"?

@MIchaelNilan The autocorrelation can be scaled in a number of ways. In the book, they use a typical scale factor of 1/N, and other definitions use other factors such as the correlation coefficients. MathWorks has a good overview of some of the different types in their documentation for xcorr.

Again, my question is, whatever the heck is $N$?  Is it the length of the sequences?  And if that is the case, then why are the limits to the summation $\pm \infty$.  Are they appending zeros to the sequences out to infinity?  Then why don't they say so?

@Envidia Got it thanks
